# Naming a template of custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-taxonomy

I am building a site in Wordpress were I have created 1 custom taxonomy named **`cars`**.

This taxonomy consists of several posts that work as follows:

- if user goes in a page of the above taxonomy  a list of cars as images is displayed.
- by clicking to a car image he is forwarded to a new page with the list of images containing the  specific car-model (brand).

My objective is to create 2 page templates as introduced by the template hierarchy:

```
taxonomy-cars.php
taxonomy-?.php
```

The first template will be named `taxonomy-cars.php`.
My problem is that I don't know how to name the second layer page template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A taxonomy is composed of terms. I suppose in your case you have the `cars` taxonomy where the "brands" are one of the possible terms.

From the [Template Hierarchy documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display):

> `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` - If the taxonomy were `sometax`, and taxonomy's term were `someterm` WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php`.

So, try `taxonomy-cars-ford.php`.